# Finding first match (only the first) in Java array

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a class assignment where we are simulating a ticket purchasing program. In this I have a method which is supposed to trawl an array and find the first match. However, the first column in each row is being returned as a match, not just the first one found.

```
//Define seatAvailable method
/**
 * seatAvailable method checks to see if a seat is available at the current price
 * @param x The array of seat prices
 * @param y The array of seats
 * @param z The price of the seat requested
 * @return The number of the seat
 */
public static int seatAvailable(int [][] x, int y [][], int z)
{
  boolean found = false;
  int seat = 0;
  while (!found)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++)
      {
        if (z == x[i][j])
        {
          found = true;
          x[i][j] = 0;
          seat = y[i][j];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return seat;
}
```

I am not looking for code as much as I am an explanation. Why is more than one item being returned as a match?

EDIT: in response to below:

```
while (!found)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++)
    { 
      if (z == x[i][j])
      {
        found = true;
        x[i][j] = 0;
        seat = y[i][j];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (found == true)
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}
return seat;
```

This is what I tried. Logging shows more than one item in the array being assigned "0".

Edit #2:
I have tried lots of variations, here is the latest. What is weird about this version is it changes 6 items in the array (in the outer loop/row) to 0 and then stops, even though their are more matches in the. If it did all or one I would understand but this perplexes me.

I think in the end it might be part of the main method doing this as I have tried many variations to break bot rows but will post this last bit anyway:

```
  public static int seatAvailable(int [][] x, int y [][], int z)
  {
    int seat = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++)
        {
          if (z == x[i][j])
          {
            x[i][j] = 0;
            seat = y[i][j];
            return seat;
          }
        }
      }
    return seat;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The break statement will break out of the innermost loop (for j).  You assume that it breaks out of the outer for loop (for i).

Here is more succinct solution that does away with the unneccessary while loop and break statements.

NOTE:  in your code you have `j <= x[0].length`.  I think it should be `j <= x[i].length` ?

```
public static int seatAvailable(int [][] x, int y [][], int z)
{
  int seat = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++)
    {
      if (z == x[i][j])
      {
        x[i][j] = 0;
        seat = y[i][j];
        return seat;
      }
    }
  }

  return seat;
}
```

Comment: It is a 2 dimensional array, hence the `x[0].length`.

Comment: PS: I am taking an intro class, so keep in mind my understanding/knowledge is remedial at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your break statement only breaks the inner loop, not the outer loop, for every loop you need a break statement to get outside of the loop, but in your case this is not necessary and dirty. But for learning purposes, I am going to demonstrate that for you:

```java
public static int seatAvailable(int [][] x, int y [][], int z)
{
  boolean found = false;
  int seat = 0;
  while (!found)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++)
      {
        if (z == x[i][j])
        {
          found = true;
          x[i][j] = 0;
          seat = y[i][j];
          break;
        }
      }
      if (found) break;
    }
  }
  return seat;
}
```

Now this will work as you expect, when the function finds the first match, first the inner loop will be broken and with the second if statement the outer for loop will be broken.

The thing is you can use a return statement to turn loop immediately and return the found seat, with this you do not need any break statements. This solution also makes the first while loop pointless, as the two for loops are sufficient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. I added the second `break` statement, and also tried removing the `while` and not using `break;` at all, but the results are now such that it is taking each match in a row and marking them zero as opposed to column.

Now I am really confused. :)

Comment: Was the code same as mine? Can you post again what you did if it was not, so I can look into that.

Comment: That is now odd, because simulating your code in edit, I had no problems, what I did was I initalized a 2 dimensional array with all values 3 and I picked 2 other values in different rows and made them 3, and then I used your function to find the first 3. So, what I am thinking is maybe when you first initialize the array, is there any chance that you do not initalize some values (leaving them as 0), because that would explain your situation. In any case, I think the problem is somewhere else in your code but not here.

Comment: I would suggest that you create another array, fill it with random values (except 0), and search a value as you wish with your function, and see if it is behaving as you would expect.

Comment: I am referencing 2 arrays, one with price that should be marked zero if a seat is found, and all values are non zero. I truncated it some but this gives ou the idea. `int [] [] seatPrice = 
    {
      {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
      {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10},
...
      {10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10},
      {20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20},
      {20, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40, 20},
      {30, 50, 50, 80, 80, 80, 80, 50, 50, 30}};`

Comment: `seatNumber = seatAvailable(seatPrice, seatPlace, validatedTicketPrice);` is the call to the seatAvailable method in main... is that correct?

Comment: So, I have some logging turned on and it shows it is trying to check after it should have stopped. I will look over the main method and make sure I am not doing anything wrong there. The odd thing is this issue does not affect the value 80; that one never makers more than one at a time.